# Facebook graph api doesnt response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook graph API is not responding.  After 10 minutes of waiting, there are no errors or response.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes, I would resolve the problem in this order:

1. Check Facebook is doing OK: Does [Facebook Platform Live Status](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status/) have any relevant information?
2. Check you have no connection issues with facebook.com in HTTPS: Can you open [the URL of the social graph for Facebook Platform's page](https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552) in your browser?
3. Check again if the actual URL you're trying to access works and the URL is correct.
4. Come back here and update the question with the problematic URL and the exact method you're trying to access, or contact Facebook Platform support.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Connection Properly, whether Your connection with Facebook API  may be broken